# Matching content between tags

Tags: php, regex

I've got a massive string containing HTML. Most of this string is variable. The only thing that's certain is that it starts with a `<table ... >` and ends with a `</table>`. The table parameters (border, style, id, class etc.) vary as well.

What I've been trying to do is to match everything in between the first and last table tags. However, I seem to fail completely.

My latest attempt is the following regex:

```
preg_match_all('~<table(.*?)>(.*?)<\/table>~is', $contents, $match);
```

A part of dummy code the regex should be working on:

```
<!-- ID: 123445 -->
<table border="1" id="id_123445" class="en_15_c01">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="c03_d11">
                <tr>
                    <td>One</td>
                    <td><span>Two</span</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>One</td>
                    <td><span>Two</span</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="blue_12">
                Some text...
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Click</a></td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span class="sp_03">
    <!-- Some more html -->
</span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bla.js" /></script>
```

Comment: You lost me at the "between tags" part.  Please _don't_ use regex to parse HTML in PHP, or any other language.  Instead, use an XML/HTML parser.  They were invented for this.

Comment: Note that "it seems to fail" is not informative.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If i were building something new and had a say in how the HTML looked, this would be the best option indeed. But the HTML I've got is not parseable by DomDocument since it's full of errors etc.

Comment: Sample code works as I'd expect, https://regex101.com/r/ARplb1/1/, so please elaborate on `seem to fail completely`. (unrelated but `/` doesn't need to be escaped when it is not the delimiter)

Comment: @user3783243 It does not match all the content of the outer table.

Comment: @Peter How doesn't it? What capture groups are you using? What data is missing?

Comment: Make it greedy. Change your regex to `<table[^>]*>[\s\S]*<\/table>`. If `s` is enabled this is enough: `<table[^>]*>.*<\/table>`

Comment: @user3783243 `preg_match('/<table(.*?)>(.*?)<\/table>/gmis', $contents, $match);` and `var_dump($match)` returns `NULL`. Using `is` it returns a partial table, cut off at the first occurence of `<table>`

Comment: @revo Thank you very much! That was what I was aiming for!

Comment: @Peter It is not NULL https://3v4l.org/vLiP3 you either have different code or a different string.